# Yii2: how to use mysql LEFT() function along with time stamp in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I need to create Client ID for my page in which client ID should be made of first 4 letters of company name + current time stamp in it.

**e.g SAMS1016 
(SAMSUNG= SAMS + time(10:16)=1016)**

Also, I need this to be auto generate, when user enter client information in form, he will enter only company name and other details Client ID field should be hidden. When user submits the form, it should take company name from company_name field and generate Client id with time stamp.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for somethings like this :

```
select concat( left('YOUR_COMPANY',4) , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%h%m ') ) from your_table;
```

Comment: can i put this in hidden field of client_code as a value?

Comment: this is SQL, like you asked in the title of question.  I don't what you are doing. If you have the ncessary  value in available in POST variable you can easy manipulate them in controller before saving,  without using SQL, but using only using PHP .

Comment: <?php
$data = $db->createCommand('select concat( left('YOUR_COMPANY',4) , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%h%m ') ) from your_table')
             ->queryColumn();

             $go=$data->company_name;

             echo $go;
?>
is this right?
getting error for above query-
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Is not right you can't. You need change `from your_table` whit a valid  table name.  And second you must surround the SQL statement with double quote.

Comment: ya i did that its just for asking, i changed accordingly but still getting this error

Comment: I see you have ` $go=$data->company_name;` this is a non sense. $data is already what you are looking for and is not a model, then can't access at attribute.  ECHO $data and you see..